# lower bound for probability of getting at least four heads in a row from 20 tosses

Tags: probability

In a book I'm reading it says the probability of getting at least four heads in a row from 20 tosses is lower bounded by $5\times 0.5^4 = 0.3125$, but how does it arrive at this? Using inclusion-exclusion, by partitioning 20 tosses into 5 separate groups, the probability that at least 1 group has 4 tosses is $5\cdot 0.5^4 - 10\cdot 0.5^8 + 10\cdot 0.5^{12} - 5\cdot 0.5^{16} + 0.5^{20} = 0.2758036$ which is far less. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: "at least 1 group has 4 tosses". Isn't the probability you've found "*exactly* 1 group has 4 tosses"?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Inclusion exclusion here gives the probability of the union so it should be at least.

Comment: OK, I am mistaken. btw, `sum (1 for i in xrange(2**20) if '1111' in bin(i))` gives `501239`, so overall probability is $501239\cdot 2^{-20}>0.478$, so there should be some other argument to show it's $>5\cdot 0.5^4$.